# PC running windows 7 Professional, black screen of death

Tags: windows-7, black-screen-of-death

So for the past couple of days I have been attempting to fix a new PC issue which I have not come across before. Before I get into the problem at hand I will give a bit of context. A friend of mine switched on their PC and was faced with the start up repair screen, instead of booting to windows as normal they accidentally started the start up repair process. After reading up on how it can take a long time to finish, they decided to switch it off midway!

Now (I assume) because of this every time the PC is started, the user is presented with a black screen with a moving cursor. I got asked if I could take a look at it, just in case as there is software with data on it which my friend wants to avoid losing. This means that it will be hard to do a clean install.

Here are some of the things I have tried:
Removed any of the unnecessary hardware - it is running on the bare essentials.
Ran chkdsk and SFC scan.
Tried rebuilding the MBC.
Changed the permissions to all files .
Started having a look at the registry, however have not done a lot with this.

Extra information:
CTRL+ALT+DEL does not work.
can not get into task manager.
Can not get into safer mode (still shows only cursor), have had to boot from recovery disk to get to cmd.
Running start up repair is of no use.
There are no restore points.
Booting from last known good config does not work.
After running chkdsk, sfc and changing folder permission the windows 7 professional background now appears, however OS still not running the shell.
The background seems to flicker occasionally, almost as if it is trying to load something or run something.

I really want to avoid doing a clean install, it is not looking positive, so I thought I would reach out and see if anyone else has solved this problem or might know what the root of the problem is?

Many thanks!
EJ

Comment: Seems like you did everything you could, and the next step is to make a backup and reinstall windows. Keep in mind that Windows 7 is EOL januari 2020, so it may be a good idea to install Windows 10 while you're at it.

Comment: The problem is doing a fresh install doesn't get me any closer to working out what caused the problem in the first place, if it is corrupt files for example, there must be a way to restore them.

Comment: It is likely that there are corrupt files, because in the end, everything, from drivers, registry and other settings are all coming down to files. You may be able to repair the install, but it will 1. taking a lot of time and effort to fix, and 2. the system will be unstable from that point forward, which probably means that it will happen again sooner or later. Also, if the root cause is a hardware issue, having made a backup and a reinstall now will prepare you for the ultimate failure, because if that is the case, then it will happen again soon on a fresh install...

Comment: ... and because you did a fresh install, you can rule out that it is a software problem right there, right then, and if the failure is the harddisk, you don't lose files, because you have your backup.

Comment: It's not the files my friend is worried about losing (they have backups already of all the files) it is the software, some of them are quite specific had quite a lot of time spent on them being set up specifically.

Comment: You can try performing a windows install OVER the current install, but it is likely that the software will have to be reinstalled that way anyway. You can also try to install windows to a different folder, then copy everything over, but that is likely to not work.

Comment: But most software, if you copy their folders from AppData and ProgramData, their settings are retained.